# プロパティ名に変数を入れたい

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

プロパティ名に変数を入れたいと思っているのですが、エラーになります。
コードは以下です。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    for (var i = 1; i <= 127; i++) {
        var hoge = "";
        hoge += "Test";
        hoge += i

        overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
           hoge: { 'DisplayForm': ConvertIcon }
        };
```

Comment: for (var i = 1; i <= 127; i++) {
    var hoge = "";
    hoge += "Test";
    hoge += i

    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
       hoge: { 'DisplayForm': ConvertIcon }
    };}閉じるのを忘れてました。ちなみに、 overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
           hoge: { 'DisplayForm': ConvertIcon }

        };ここのhogeにTest１～Test127を入れたいと思っています。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　自分の投稿は，投稿の下の「編集」から自由に書き足せますのでお試しください．また，コード部分はそこを範囲選択してエディタの上の `{}` ボタンを押すと綺麗に装飾できます．

Answer (score 3):

オブジェクトのプロパティに`[プロパティ名]`を使用してアクセスします。

```
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {};
for (var i = 1; i <= 127; i++) {
    var hoge = "";
    hoge += "Test";
    hoge += i

    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields[hoge] = { value: hoge };
}
```